# Dedup field by timeslice in splunk

Tags: splunk

I am looking to see how many servers are reporting into splunk over time.  This is a query similar to the one I have tried:

```
sourcetype=defined | dedup host | timechart count by pop
```

What is happening is the host gets `dedup`ed before the time chart (obviously) so I'm not exactly getting the results I'm looking for.

How can I deduplicate the server list per time slice in the timechart?

Please let me know if further clarification is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the option I was looking for was the distinct_count function for charts.  This is the final query that is returning results that I am looking for:

```
sourcetype=defined | timechart dc(host) by pop
```